# How to take plan details in onclick the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i have one form and three button,suppose if i am clicking Enroll Now button means i have take the plan details like

1. Contacts details up to ?
2. Bonus Contact details up to  ?
3. Area Master Assistance : No ?
4. Contact details through sms ?

Above values i want to take how can take ? i tried i can able to take plan name which i have selected but i am not able to take plan details

```js
  $(".payNow").on("click", function(e) {
    var $list = $(this).closest(".pricing-table");
      name = $list.find(".myTitle").text();

    console.log(name);
  });
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid plan-background" style="margin-top: 0%;padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;">
  <div class="container main_btm" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px; ">

  <div class="row top" style="margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;margin-top:22px;">
         
  <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 hidden-xs" class-align="right" style="margin-top: 10px;padding:left:23px; ">

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mobile-property-list" style="margin-top: 10px; padding-left: 27px;"><h4 style="color:#fff;font-size:20px;"> Select Your Plan</h4></br>  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-0 hidden-xs"></div>

  </div>

  <div class="row mobile-filter"  style="margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;margin-bottom:5%;" >

  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-10 top-a rentListing" style="padding-left:0px;">

  <section id="pricing-table">
                <div class="row pricelistNew">
                    <div class="pricing">
                       
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="pricing-table">
                                <div class="pricing-header">
                                    <p class="pricing-title myTitle">Easy Plan </p>
         <input type="hidden" value="1 " name="plan_Id" class="plan_Id">
                                    
                                    <p class="pricing-rate">₹ 1000 <br><span>Including All Tax</span></p>
                  
          <a class="btn btn-custom payNow">Buy Now</a>
                  
                                </div>

                                <div class="pricing-list">
                                    <ul>
           <li>Contacts details up to : 25</li>
            <li>Bonus Contact details up to : 2</li>
            <li>Area Master Assistance : No</li>
            <li>Contact details through sms : Yes</li>
           </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="pricing-table">
                                <div class="pricing-header">
                                    <p class="pricing-title myTitle">Cool Plan </p>
         <input type="hidden" value="2 " name="plan_Id" class="plan_Id">
                                    
                                    <p class="pricing-rate">₹ 2000 <br><span>Including All Tax</span></p>
                  
         <a class="btn btn-custom payNow">Buy Now</a>
                  
                                </div>

                                <div class="pricing-list">
                                    <ul>
           <li>Contacts details up to : 48</li>
            <li>Bonus Contact details up to : 4</li>
            <li>Area Master Assistance : Yes</li>
            <li>Contact details through sms : Yes</li>
           </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="pricing-table">
                                <div class="pricing-header">
                                    <p class="pricing-title myTitle">Free Plan </p>
         <input type="hidden" value="3 " name="plan_Id" class="plan_Id">
                                    
                                    <p class="pricing-rate">₹ 0 <br><span>Including All Tax</span></p>
                                         
                                    <a class="btn btn-custom payNow" style="">Enroll Now</a>
                  
                  
                                </div>

                                <div class="pricing-list">
                                    <ul>
           <li>Contacts details up to : 5</li>
            <li>Bonus Contact details up to : 00</li>
            <li>Area Master Assistance : No</li>
            <li>Contact details through sms : Yes</li>
           </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       </div>
                </div>
        </section>

  </div>

  <div class="col-md-1 "></div>
  </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `form`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use data attribute of HTML5 and get value back in jQuery using following way.

```js
 $(".payNow").on("click", function(e) {
    var $list = $(this).closest(".pricing-table");
      name = $list.find(".myTitle").text();
      contact_upto = $list.find(".pricing-list ul").attr("data-contact-upto");
      bonus_upto = $list.find(".pricing-list ul").attr("data-bonus-upto");
      AMA = $list.find(".pricing-list ul").attr("data-AMA");
      sms = $list.find(".pricing-list ul").attr("data-sms");
      console.log(contact_upto);
  });
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid plan-background" style="margin-top: 0%;padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;">
  <div class="container main_btm" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px; ">

  <div class="row top" style="margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;margin-top:22px;">
         
  <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 hidden-xs" class-align="right" style="margin-top: 10px;padding:left:23px; ">

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mobile-property-list" style="margin-top: 10px; padding-left: 27px;"><h4 style="color:#fff;font-size:20px;"> Select Your Plan</h4></br>  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-0 hidden-xs"></div>

  </div>

  <div class="row mobile-filter"  style="margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;margin-bottom:5%;" >

  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-10 top-a rentListing" style="padding-left:0px;">

  <section id="pricing-table">
                <div class="row pricelistNew">
                    <div class="pricing">
                       
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="pricing-table">
                                <div class="pricing-header">
                                    <p class="pricing-title myTitle">Easy Plan </p>
         <input type="hidden" value="1 " name="plan_Id" class="plan_Id">
                                    
                                    <p class="pricing-rate">₹ 1000 <br><span>Including All Tax</span></p>
                  
          <a class="btn btn-custom payNow">Buy Now</a>
                  
                                </div>

                                <div class="pricing-list">
                                    <ul data-contact-upto="25" data-bonus-upto="2" data-AMA="No" data-sms="Yes">
           <li>Contacts details up to : 25</li>
            <li>Bonus Contact details up to : 2</li>
            <li>Area Master Assistance : No</li>
            <li>Contact details through sms : Yes</li>
           </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="pricing-table">
                                <div class="pricing-header">
                                    <p class="pricing-title myTitle">Cool Plan </p>
         <input type="hidden" value="2 " name="plan_Id" class="plan_Id">
                                    
                                    <p class="pricing-rate">₹ 2000 <br><span>Including All Tax</span></p>
                  
         <a class="btn btn-custom payNow">Buy Now</a>
                  
                                </div>

                                <div class="pricing-list">
                                   <ul data-contact-upto="48" data-bonus-upto="4" data-AMA="Yes" data-sms="Yes">
           <li>Contacts details up to : 48</li>
            <li>Bonus Contact details up to : 4</li>
            <li>Area Master Assistance : Yes</li>
            <li>Contact details through sms : Yes</li>
           </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="pricing-table">
                                <div class="pricing-header">
                                    <p class="pricing-title myTitle">Free Plan </p>
         <input type="hidden" value="3 " name="plan_Id" class="plan_Id">
                                    
                                    <p class="pricing-rate">₹ 0 <br><span>Including All Tax</span></p>
                                         
                                    <a class="btn btn-custom payNow" style="">Enroll Now</a>
                  
                  
                                </div>

                                <div class="pricing-list">
                                    <ul data-contact-upto="5" data-bonus-upto="0" data-AMA="No" data-sms="Yes">
           <li>Contacts details up to : 5</li>
            <li>Bonus Contact details up to : 00</li>
            <li>Area Master Assistance : No</li>
            <li>Contact details through sms : Yes</li>
           </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       </div>
                </div>
        </section>

  </div>

  <div class="col-md-1 "></div>
  </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap you text values inside `span` tag and give a suitable class.

```js
  $(function(){
 
 
  $(".payNow").on("click", function(e) {
    var $list = $(this).closest(".pricing-table");
      name = $list.find(".myTitle").text();
      console.log(name);
   var parentEl= $(this).parents().closest('.pricing-header');
   var nextEl= $(parentEl).next().children();
   console.log('Contact Details :'+$(nextEl).children().find('.contactDetails').text()); 
   console.log('Bonus Contact :'+$(nextEl).children().find('.bonusContacts').text()); 
   console.log('Area Master :'+$(nextEl).children().find('.areaMaster').text()); 
   console.log('Contact details SMS :'+$(nextEl).children().find('.ContactDetailsSMS').text()); 
  });
  });
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid plan-background" style="margin-top: 0%;padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;">
  <div class="container main_btm" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px; ">

  <div class="row top" style="margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;margin-top:22px;">
         
  <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 hidden-xs" class-align="right" style="margin-top: 10px;padding:left:23px; ">

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mobile-property-list" style="margin-top: 10px; padding-left: 27px;"><h4 style="color:#fff;font-size:20px;"> Select Your Plan</h4></br>  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-0 hidden-xs"></div>

  </div>

  <div class="row mobile-filter"  style="margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;margin-bottom:5%;" >

  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-10 top-a rentListing" style="padding-left:0px;">

  <section id="pricing-table">
                <div class="row pricelistNew">
                    <div class="pricing">
                       
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="pricing-table">
                                <div class="pricing-header">
                                    <p class="pricing-title myTitle">Easy Plan </p>
         <input type="hidden" value="1 " name="plan_Id" class="plan_Id">
                                    
                                    <p class="pricing-rate">₹ 1000 <br><span>Including All Tax</span></p>
                  
          <a class="btn btn-custom payNow">Buy Now</a>
                  
                                </div>

                                <div class="pricing-list">
                                    <ul>
           <li>Contacts details up to : <span class='contactDetails'>05</span></li>
            <li>Bonus Contact details up to : <span class="bonusContacts"> 20</span></li>
            <li>Area Master Assistance : <span class='areaMaster'>No </span></li>
            <li>Contact details through sms : <span class='ContactDetailsSMS'>No</span></li>
           </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="pricing-table">
                                <div class="pricing-header">
                                    <p class="pricing-title myTitle">Cool Plan </p>
         <input type="hidden" value="2 " name="plan_Id" class="plan_Id">
                                    
                                    <p class="pricing-rate">₹ 2000 <br><span>Including All Tax</span></p>
                  
         <a class="btn btn-custom payNow">Buy Now</a>
                  
                                </div>

                                <div class="pricing-list">
                                    <ul>
           <li>Contacts details up to : <span class='contactDetails'>50</span></li>
            <li>Bonus Contact details up to : <span class="bonusContacts"> 8</span></li>
            <li>Area Master Assistance : <span class='areaMaster'>Yes</span></li>
            <li>Contact details through sms : <span class='ContactDetailsSMS'>Yes</span></li>
           </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="pricing-table">
                                <div class="pricing-header">
                                    <p class="pricing-title myTitle">Free Plan </p>
         <input type="hidden" value="3 " name="plan_Id" class="plan_Id">
                                    
                                    <p class="pricing-rate">₹ 0 <br><span>Including All Tax</span></p>
                                         
                                    <a class="btn btn-custom payNow" style="">Enroll Now</a>
                  
                  
                                </div>

                                <div class="pricing-list">
                                    <ul>
           <li>Contacts details up to : <span class='contactDetails'>25</span></li>
            <li>Bonus Contact details up to : <span class="bonusContacts"> 2</span></li>
            <li>Area Master Assistance : <span class='areaMaster'>No </span></li>
            <li>Contact details through sms : <span class='ContactDetailsSMS'>Yes</span></li>
           </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       </div>
                </div>
        </section>

  </div>

  <div class="col-md-1 "></div>
  </div>

  </div>
```